# [Perl]: Not a CODE reference ... my 1st script

Tags: multithreading, perl

i am getting the following error when i am trying to run my 1st Perl script:

```
[id=0 @ 0] : IP address "3.3.3.3" corresponds to device "core". 
Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Not a CODE reference at ./dev_ithread.pl line 23.
[id=0 @ 1] : IP address "5.5.5.5" corresponds to device "border". 
Thread 2 terminated abnormally: Not a CODE reference at ./dev_ithread.pl line 23.
```

and here is what i have written so far

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use diagnostics ;
use threads ;
use Config ;

$Config{useithreads} || die("\n---> Please recompile Perl with \<ithreads\> included. \n") ;


# IP parameterization of network elements.
my %device_ip = ( 
            "core" => "3.3.3.3",
            "border" => "5.5.5.5",      
        ) ;

# Initialize devices' pool of threads.
my $index = 0 ;
my @device_thread = () ;
while( my ($key, $value) = each %device_ip )    
{ 
    push( @device_thread, threads->new(\&thread_job($key, $device_ip{$key}, $index))->join ) ;  $index = $index+1 ;
}

# Worker thread subroutine.
sub thread_job
{
    my ($device, $ip, $index) = @_ ;

    my $ithread = threads->tid() ;
    print "[id=$ithread @ $index] : IP address \"$ip\" corresponds to device \"$device\". \n" ;
}
```

i would be thankful, if someone could help me overcome this problem.
thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The first argument to `threads->new()` must be a code reference or the name of a function. You are executing the function and try to take a code reference of the result (which is most likely a true value since that is what `print` returns), hence the error. I guess your call should be like this:

```
threads->new(\&thread_job, $key, $device_ip{$key}, $index)->join
```

Comment: @user690182: Great. You can now accept one of the answers that you think helped best solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

`\&thread_job($key, $device_ip{$key}, $index)` doesn't do what you think it does:  it runs `thread_job(...)` immediately, then produces a reference to its result.  `threads->new` then tries to execute that reference inside the new thread, which doesn't work because it's not a reference to a `sub`.

You probably want to say `sub { thread_job($key, $device_ip{$key}, $index) }` instead.  (Or @musiKk's version.)

Comment: I always use my version. But I'm curious: Has creating an anonymous sub any benefits?

Comment: @musiKk: It's more convenient for quick stuff and easier to read quickly when scanning through code, but if you want to use some kinds of variables as arguments it can sometimes behave weirdly due to Perl's somewhat odd notion of how package variables interact with closures.  (Lexicals are captured by the closure, but package variables will use the value they have when the closure is invoked, not when it was created.)  Your way is more reliable and preferred for those, and in a real program instead of a quick test would be preferred here.